# Making connection to MySql db in a custom Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, groovy

I am completely new to Gradle so any hints, advice, answers welcome.

My situation: I have been tasked with writing a custom Gradle plugin, a part of which is to query a remote MySql db. I wrote the code in Groovy/Java and in a standard groovy project it all works perfectly.

However, when I then migrated the code to the plugin everything worked fine except I cannot establish a db connection.

build.gradle

```
// Apply plugins
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'

// Repository
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Dependencies
dependencies {

    // Spock testing and specification framework
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile gradleApi()

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version:    '1.13'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tukaani/xz
    compile group: 'org.tukaani', name: 'xz', version: '1.6'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.41'
    }

    group='com.scanImage'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: uri('../repo'))
            }
        }
    }
```

Implementation class

```
package com.scanImage.gradle

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

class runScanImage implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.task('scan') << {
            def imageScan = new ScanImage('java', '/home/Paul/')
            imageScan.scanDockerImage()
        }
    }
}
```

ScanImage class calling method to make connection

```
package com.scanImage.gradle

class ScanImage {



    // Start the scan process
    void scanDockerImage() {

        //Some other code...

        // Query the database
        def connection = new DBInterface()
        connection.connect()
        //connection.queryDB(jarList)
        //connection.closeDB()

    }

}
```

DBInterface class to make DB connection/query db

```
package com.scanImage.gradle

/**
 * Created by Paul on 3/14/17.
 */
import java.sql.*

class DBInterface {

    Connection conn = null
    Statement stmt = null
    ResultSet rs = null

    void connect() {
        try {
            // Create database connection
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myDb", "myName", "myPassword")


            println("Connected to DB")
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            println "No connection found!"
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

//some db queries...
}
```

I "gradle clean build" and "gradle uploadArchives" to create the plugin jar etc. then "gradle scan" to execute the plugin functionality from the user perspective.

User build.gradle class to execute plugin functionality.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url uri('../repo')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group:'com.scanImage', name: 'runScanImage',
                version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'scanImage'
```

The plugin compiles and builds correctly and will execute all functionality prior to trying to establish the db connection. When i execute the "gradle scan -S" from the users perspective I get the following error:

```
No connection found!
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://myDb
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0
```

I have search stack overflow as thoroughly as I can (maybe I'm not asking the correct questions) and have tried to implement various fixes to (kinda) similar problems but cannot find an exact instance to match mine.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The driver is not in the classpath during runtime, only during compile time. @See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: Hmmm, ok. But I'm still a little confused. By default, isn't everything put on Gradle's compile configuration also visible on its runtime configuration? I'm still not sure what a solution to my issue is?

Comment: I tried putting " runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6' " in the build.gradle script and am still getting the same error. Am I even close to doing the right thing?